# Oracle:Update row based on resultset count

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to update below table based on number of rows returned.
If the result set returns only 1 row then set stat to N ,if count>1 or count<1 do not update anything.

so my first query returns id(we have to send returned id from this query to update query)
and second query should update only if the result set have only one row.

```
    create table person(id number(10),stat char(1));
    insert into person(id,stat)values(123,'Y');
    insert into person(id,stat)values(123,'Y');
    insert into person(id,stat)values(345,'Y');
    commit;
```

Input:

[image]

**output:**

for example my select query returned id=345

[image]

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This update will set **stat** to **N** if that id only appears once.

```sql
UPDATE person p1
   SET p1.stat = 'N'
 WHERE p1.id IN (  SELECT p2.id
                     FROM person p2
                 GROUP BY p2.id
                   HAVING COUNT (*) = 1);
```

Comment: is there any way we can take the result from select first and pass that to update reason is i using this select result in other insert statements too.

Comment: You can try a select statement like this: `SELECT id, stat, CASE COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) WHEN 1 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS new_stat FROM person`

Comment: How do we pass this the result to update and insert statements in oracle